# Getting Invariant Violation : invariant violation 47 on mutation query in appolo graphql

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo, hasura

I am using a mutation query to take the input from user and update it in database but while updating it is throwing this error invariant violation which I am not able to understand, In mutation I have four objects with min and max value that is coming from user:

```
export const ADD_INSIGHT_META_DATA = gql`
mutation MyMutation ($data : [projectInsightsMetadata_insert_input!]!) {
    insert_projectInsightsMetadata(objects: $data) {
      returning {
        id
        createdAt
      }
    }
  }
`
```

This is how I am using the above query :

```
export const updateScheduleInsightMetaData = async(InsertData:any )=>{
    const response:ApolloQueryResult<any> = await client.query({
        query:ADD_INSIGHT_META_DATA,
        context:{
            role:"updateMasterPlan",
            token:getProjectExchangeToken()
        },
        fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
        variables:{
        data:InsertData
        }
    })
    return response.data;
}
```

Now I am using updateScheduleInsightMetaData function in one of code :

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { IconButton, makeStyles, Paper, TextField, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Box } from "@mui/system";

import {getScheduleInsightMetaData,updateScheduleInsightMetaData} from "./InsightsSettingsActions";
import { setIsLoading } from "src/modules/root/context/authentication/action";
import { stateContext } from "src/modules/root/context/authentication/authContext";
import Notification, { AlertTypes } from "src/modules/shared/components/Toaster/Toaster";
import { projectDetailsContext } from "src/modules/baseService/projects/Context/ProjectDetailsContext";
import {
    decodeExchangeToken,
    getProjectExchangeToken
  } from "../../../../../services/authservice";
  import "./InsightsSettings.scss";
   import NoDataMessage from "src/modules/shared/components/NoDataMessage/NoDataMessage";

  interface Params {
    projectId:any
}
interface InputType{
    min:number,
    max:number
}

export const noPermissionMessage = "You don't have permission to view project insight settings";

const InsightsSettings: React.FC =()=>{
    const { projectDetailsState }: any = useContext(projectDetailsContext);
    const { dispatch, stateCont }: any = useContext(stateContext);
    const {projectId} = useParams<Params>();
    const [hasCreateAccess, setCreateAccess] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [informationalConstraints, setInformationalConstraints] = useState<any>({min:Number(""),max:Number("")});
    const [rfiResponse, setRfiResponse] = useState<any>({min:Number(""),max:Number("")});
    const [physicalConstraints, setPhysicalConstraints] = useState<any>({min:Number(""),max:Number("")});
    const [managementConstraints, setManagementConstraints] = useState<any>({min:Number(""),max:Number("")});
    const tenantId = decodeExchangeToken().tenantId;

    console.log("informationalConstraints",informationalConstraints);
    console.log("rfiResponse",rfiResponse);
    console.log("physicalConstraints",physicalConstraints);
    console.log("managementConstraints",managementConstraints);
    const projectToken = getProjectExchangeToken();
    useEffect(()=>{
    
      setCreateAccess(decodeExchangeToken(projectToken).allowedRoles.includes("viewMasterPlan"))
    },[projectToken])

    const navigateback = () => {
       // props.navBack();
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
       
        const token = projectDetailsState.projectToken;
          fetchInsightsData(projectId,tenantId,token)
      },[projectId,tenantId])
  
      const fetchInsightsData = async(projectId:any,tenantId:any,token:any)=>{
        try{
          // const tenantId = decodeExchangeToken().tenantId;
          // const token = projectDetailsState.projectToken;
          dispatch(setIsLoading(true));
          const res = await getScheduleInsightMetaData(projectId, tenantId ,token)
          dispatch(setIsLoading(false));
  
        }catch(err){
          console.log("error in fetching  insights metadata",err)
          Notification.sendNotification('An error occured while fetching insights metadata', AlertTypes.warn);
          dispatch(setIsLoading(false));
        }
      }


      const handleInformationalInputChange = (e:any)=>{
        setInformationalConstraints((prevState:any)=>({...prevState,[e.target.name]:Number(e.target.value)}))
      }
      const handleRfiInputChange = (e:any)=>{
        setRfiResponse((prevState:any)=>({...prevState,[e.target.name]:Number(e.target.value)}))
      }
      const handlePhysicalInputChange = (e:any)=>{
        setPhysicalConstraints((prevState:any)=>({...prevState,[e.target.name]:Number(e.target.value)}))
      }
      const handleManagementInputChange = (e:any)=>{
        setManagementConstraints((prevState:any)=>({...prevState,[e.target.name]:Number(e.target.value)}))
      }

      const handleUpdate = async(e:any,informationalConstraints:any,rfiResponse:any,physicalConstraints:any,managementConstraints:any)=>{
     try{
        dispatch(setIsLoading(true));
        const data = {
            LeadtimeMgmntConstraints:managementConstraints,
            LeadtimePhysicalConstraints:physicalConstraints,
            ChangeOrderIssueReview:rfiResponse,
            RFIReviewResponse:informationalConstraints
        }
         const response = await updateScheduleInsightMetaData(data)
       // const response = await updateScheduleInsightMetaData(managementConstraints,physicalConstraints,rfiResponse,informationalConstraints)
        Notification.sendNotification("Successfully updated insights", AlertTypes.success);
        dispatch(setIsLoading(false));
     }catch(err){
        dispatch(setIsLoading(false));
        Notification.sendNotification(err, AlertTypes.warn);
        console.log(err)
     }
      }

    return(
         <>
        {hasCreateAccess?
        <div className="InsightsSettings">
        <>
        <div  className="InsightsSettings__header">
        <Typography component="p">Insight Settings</Typography>
        </div>      
        <div className="InsightsSettings__input_area">
            <div className="InsightsSettings__individual_box">
               <Typography component="p">How far ahead of an activity start does the team review and resolve management or informational constraints?</Typography>
               <div className="InsightsSettings__constraints">
                <input name="min"   className="InsightsSettings__constraints__style" value={informationalConstraints.min} placeholder="min" onChange={handleInformationalInputChange}/>
                <input name="max"   className="InsightsSettings__constraints__style" value={informationalConstraints.max} placeholder="max" onChange={handleInformationalInputChange}/>
                </div>
               
               </div>
                <div className="InsightsSettings__individual_box">
                <Typography component="p">What is the average (or typical) RFI design response period for this project?</Typography>
                <div className="InsightsSettings__constraints">
                <input name="min"   className="InsightsSettings__constraints__style" value={rfiResponse.min} placeholder="min" onChange={handleRfiInputChange}/>
                <input name="max"   className="InsightsSettings__constraints__style" value={rfiResponse.max} placeholder="max" onChange={handleRfiInputChange}/>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div className="InsightsSettings__individual_box">
                <Typography component="p">How far ahead of an activity start does the team review and resolve physical or site constraints ?</Typography>
                <div className="InsightsSettings__constraints">
                <input name="min"   className="InsightsSettings__constraints__style" value={physicalConstraints.min} placeholder="min" onChange={handlePhysicalInputChange}/>
                <input name="max"   className="InsightsSettings__constraints__style" value={physicalConstraints.max} placeholder="max" onChange={handlePhysicalInputChange}/>
                </div>
                </div>
               <div className="InsightsSettings__individual_box">
               <Typography component="p">How far ahead of an activity start does the team review and resolve management or informational constraints?</Typography>
               <div className="InsightsSettings__constraints">
               <input name="min"   className="InsightsSettings__constraints__style" value={managementConstraints.min} placeholder="min" onChange={handleManagementInputChange}/>
               <input name="max"   className="InsightsSettings__constraints__style" value={managementConstraints.max} placeholder="max" onChange={handleManagementInputChange}/>
               </div>
               
               </div>
        </div>
        </>
                     <div className="InsightsSettings__action-button">
                        <Button data-testid={'cancel-update'} variant="outlined" onClick={navigateback} className="cancel-button">
                            Cancel
                        </Button>
                        <Button  
                            variant="outlined"
                            className="update-button"
                           onClick={(e:any)=>{handleUpdate(e,informationalConstraints,rfiResponse,physicalConstraints,managementConstraints)}}
                            >
                            Update
                        </Button>
                    </div>
        </div>: (
                    <div className="noCreatePermission-insight">
                        <div className="no-permission-insight">
                            <NoDataMessage message={noPermissionMessage}/> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )      }
         </>
    )
}
export default InsightsSettings
```

When I am clicking on update button to make the insertion in database I am getting invariant violation: 47 error ,I am pasting the error here

```
Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: 47 (see https://github.com/apollographql/invariant-packages)
    at new InvariantError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:327507:24)
    at invariant (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:327521:11)
    at getQueryDefinition (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:9716:230)
    at StoreReader.diffQueryAgainstStore (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:2449:286)
    at InMemoryCache.diff (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:1132:29)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:4864:28
    at perform (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:1264:31)
    at InMemoryCache.batch (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:1288:7)
    at InMemoryCache.performTransaction (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:1321:17)
    at QueryInfo.markResult (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:4842:20)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:5713:19
    at both (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:10788:20)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:10777:26
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.then (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:10776:16)
    at Object.next (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:10791:39)
    at notifySubscription (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:332559:18)
    at onNotify (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:332603:3)
    at SubscriptionObserver.next (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:332652:5)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:10848:23
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at iterateObserversSafely (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:10847:23)
    at Object.next (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:10586:87)
    at notifySubscription (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:332559:18)
    at onNotify (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:332603:3)
    at SubscriptionObserver.next (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:332652:5)
    at Object.next (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:6773:22)
    at notifySubscription (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:332559:18)
    at onNotify (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:332603:3)
    at SubscriptionObserver.next (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:332652:5)
    at notifySubscription (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:332559:18)
    at onNotify (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:332603:3)
    at SubscriptionObserver.next (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:332652:5)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:7061:18
```

Comment: I don't have the answer, but I have a next step for you: the error you pasted has a URL in it that tells you to look at the file `node_modules/@apollo/client/invariantErrorCodes.js` in your local directory to find out what this invariant error is.

Comment: @DanCrews thankyou!!, I was able to solve my problem after after going throught this file you have mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going to the github url provided in error i.e https://github.com/apollographql/invariant-packages  it tells to go into particular file in your node-modules to get the more understanding of invariant number error

`node_modules/@apollo/client/invariantErrorCodes.js`
after going into above file they have provided some extra information related to error code so for me I was getting invariant violation: 47

```
47: {
    file: "@apollo/client/utilities/graphql/getFromAST.js",
    node: invariant(queryDef && queryDef.operation === 'query', 'Must contain a query definition.')
  },
```

In my case I am having mutation query and trying to query it instead of doing mutation that's why I was getting error so the changes that I did in my code to make it working is :

**Instead of doing this:**

```
export const updateScheduleInsightMetaData = async(InsertData:any )=>{
    const response:ApolloQueryResult<any> = await client.query({
        query:ADD_INSIGHT_META_DATA,
        context:{
            role:"updateMasterPlan",
            token:getProjectExchangeToken()
        },
        fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
        variables:{
        data:InsertData
        }
    })
    return response.data;
}
```

**I needed to do this:**

```
export const updateScheduleInsightMetaData = async(InsightsData:any )=>{
    const response = await client.mutate({
        mutation:ADD_INSIGHT_META_DATA,
        context:{
            role:"updateMasterPlan",
            token:getProjectExchangeToken()
        },
        fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
        variables:{
        data:InsightsData
        }
    })
    return response.data;
}
```